# How to add default value to array using foreach

Tags: laravel

Hello i have a table with many columns, each column has a row called phone_number now this row can either be null or filled with 1 or more phone numbers so its serialized the value. Now i want to fetch the phone numbers and this is the code i have until now

```
    foreach ($myActions as $action) {
        if ($action->phone_number) {
            $phoneArray = unserialize($action->phone_number);
        }
    }
```

I want to add a default value like ---- so when i make this code:

```
<td>
@foreach($phoneArray as $phone)
    <p class="badge badge-info"> {{ $phone }} </p>
@endforeach
</td>
```

To show result:

```
1
*----*
2
3
4
*----*
```

Comment: You can do like this in your view `{{$phone ?? '----';}}`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create any default value.
You can use the PHP Null coalescing operator: `??`, which will output the second expression if `$phone` is null

```
<td>
 @foreach($phoneArray as $phone)
  <p class="badge badge-info"> {{ $phone ?? '*----*'}} </p>
 @endforeach
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check when variable phone is not empty

```
<td>
@foreach($phoneArray as $phone)
    <p class="badge badge-info"> {{ !empty($phone) ? $phone : "----" }} </p>
@endforeach
</td>
```